# Transaction log file - Migration SSMA

Tags: oracle, migration, transaction-log, ssma

I'm attempting to migrate a relatively large Oracle DB to MSSQL using SSMA however due to disk space constraints, I had to stop the full migration last night when it was 50% of the way through.

[image: data_usage]

Upon investigating disk space usage, I've found that the transaction log file is nearly 3x the size of the data files.

Is there any way I can get this down?
Would you recommend deleting the new DB and starting again from scratch?
Would the Transaction log file have normalised in size if I let SSMA complete the migration?

I've tried shrinking the txn log to no avail.

Any help here is appreciated.

Cheers
Mark